# Password Char can't reset to default

Tags: c#, authentication

I am using "●" as the password character for my login form.  I have a check box there titled "Show Password".  If a person clicks on "show password" the "●" should be removed and the password should be shown as actual text.  I am not able to do that; here is the code:

```
    private void LoginForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Passtxt.PasswordChar = '●';

            if (checkBox_Showpass.Checked == true)
            {
                Passtxt.PasswordChar = '\0';
            }
    }
```

Comment: What code do you have in the CheckedChanged event of your checkbox? If you want to restore the correct password char you need to work there.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`UseSystemPasswordChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.usesystempasswordchar(v=vs.110).aspx) property to enable or disable password mode:

```
private void checkBox_Showpass_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox_Showpass.Checked == true)
        Passtxt.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
    else
        Passtxt.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
}
```

Comment: It then says: cant convert char to bool.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally got that to work: Copied the if statement and pasted that into checkBox_Showpass_CheckedChanged method:

```
    private void checkBox_Showpass_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox_Showpass.Checked == true)
        {
            this.Passtxt.PasswordChar = '\0';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just `this.Passtxt.UseSystemPasswordChar = !checkBox_Showpass.Checked` to enable the toggle